# How to develop Azure Functions app offline using Microsoft SignalR?

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-functions, azure-signalr

I have an application using Azure Functions and would like to add Azure SignalR. During development, myself and the other developers would like to avoid our local (potentially modified) applications talking to each other through SignalR.

Does any tool exist that would allow us to emulate / run SignalR offline for the purposes of development only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Azure SignalR Service through the Azure portal, then no.

**However, there's a free tier of the SignalR Service which you could use.** Depending on the size of your dev team you could just create an instance each.